# How to make a screenreader pronounce C# correctly

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

On my website, I reference the programming language C#. A screen reader will read this as "C number".

Is it worth trying to force a screenreader pronounce "C sharp"?

If so, I have tried `<span aria-label="C sharp">C#</span>`, but the `<span>` stops the screenreaders flow... And even when I hover the 'C#' text, it is still pronounced "C number".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you can try something like [making element only visible to screen readers using custom css](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/applied-accessibility/make-elements-only-visible-to-a-screen-reader-by-using-custom-css) and then do `<span class="sr-only">C sharp</span><span aria-hidden="true">C#</span>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrap it in `abbr` tags and provide `C Sharp` as the title attribute. You are adding semantic meaning to your markup that can then be used by assistive technology. It's not really worth trying to force a screen reader to read it correctly as you'll likely make things confusing and most users will set their screen reader to read abbreviations to their own preference.

```html
<abbr title="C Sharp">C#</abbr>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I add an extra `span` to hide the real `C#`, and use `aria-label="C sharp"` in the wrapper element instead. It works for me.

```html
<span aria-label="C sharp">
  <span aria-hidden="true">C#</span>
</span>
```

Comment: `aria-label` on a non-semantic element such as a `<span>` is ignored by screen readers.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/using-aria/#label-support

Comment: @slugolicious thanks for your reminder. I"ll check it again. When using nvda, it works for me.

Comment: I would follow the recommendation of the official spec that I posted in my previous comment, whether or not you find a screen reader that allows it.